# Bootstrap - How to load buttons dynamically from MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql, twitter-bootstrap, button, dynamic, load

In Bootstrap 3.3.4 I want to create a row of buttons where the button text, colours and icon are loaded from a MySQL database. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, but obviously you'd need to do this with some kind of javascript or back-end hook.  You can't just grab data from a database on the client side

Comment: The answer is Yes. you need to work on it and come back post a question if you have problems

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question is **yes**.
There are a lot of ways to achieve that. As a starter you can Convert your CSS to PHP:

For instance:

```
<style>
// Get styles from DB
#custom { background: #<?php echo $colour; ?> }
</style>
```

Here is a [link](http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/csscolor/) for additional info on the subject

Comment: Thanks Alundra.The issue I am facing is that I am running the entire system within Node Webkit so PHP won't work.  Or is there a way around that?